# locating hide element using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I have an element that after clicking the button it builds a div with Ajax and I can't get the element.

[image]

Click button:

[image]

Show div:

[image]

But in my code doesn't work

```
vv = drive.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vUPDATE_0001"]')
```

Error Message:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="vUPDATE_0001"]"}
```

Comment: Can you share those HTML in text format here

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to wait until the `div` is visible. Luckily, selenium has just that!
You can read more over [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

By using `WebDriverWait` along with `expected_conditions`, your example code would look like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

timeout = 10 # Wait 10 seconds. If it doesn't appear in 10 seconds then throw an error

vv = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="vUPDATE_0001"]')))
```

For many different circumstances, there are different conditions, such as wait for an element to be clickable, or wait an alert to pop up. We are using presence of element located, which is the same as `find_element_by_[condition]`. Then we are setting the condition with `By.XPATH`. There are many different conditions which represent their `find_element_by_` alternative, such as `By.ID`, `By.CLASS_NAME`, and `By.NAME`.